# Phing build xml file hanging after sudo su to a user but normal command line execution works

Tags: phing

Following is a section of my build.xml file -

```
<echo level="warning">Flow 1</echo>
                        <exec command="sudo su auto_deploy" dir="${dir.jenkins_base}/${dir.scratchpad}" />
                        <echo level="warning">Flow 2</echo>
```

And on running `phing` while logged in as user auto_deploy or some other user, the output is -

```
 [echo] Flow 1
```

Something seems to be wrong with the `sudo su` command.

However, if I simply run `sudo su auto_deploy` from command line, it works regardless of which user I am currently logged in as.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to execute Phing as sudo?:

`$ sudo bin/phing deploy`